# How to install PHP clamav on CENTOS

Tags: php, centos, antivirus

I need to install clamav to be used on php. How can I do it? I have tried to google how to install clamav, but most instructions either install clam av correctly, but not the php package, or missing dependencies, or similar problems.

Comment: are you using YUM? do you have the EPEL repo active?

Comment: [Install EPEL](http://www.centosblog.com/enable-epel-repo-on-centos-5-and-centos-6/) then `yum install clamav clamd`

Comment: In general, requests for "step by step instructions" are not a good fit here, and generally they get closed. It is much better to explain what you've tried, and where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to install ClamAV like normal (with the epel repo)...

```
yum install clamav
yum install clamav-devel
```

If you don't have EPEL you can get it from IUS community (if you want you can also grab the IUS repo and get the latest version of PHP) - *thank the RackSpace engineers for this!*

```
wget http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
```

Then you download and install [this library](http://php-clamav.sourceforge.net/), which will handle all the hard things for you.

```
wget **the direct link you got**
tar -xvzf php-clamav_0.15.7.tar.gz
cd php-clamav-0.15.7
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Now add the extension to your /etc/php.ini

```
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/clamav.so
```

Remember to change the path to what was given to you by `make install`

then restart your Apache

```
service httpd restart
```

Make a file with the contents:

```
<?php
    echo cl_info();
```

It should come up with something like this:
[image]

Now you should have access to all the library functions, you can now scan files like this:

```
$retcode = cl_scanfile($file, $virus_name);

if ($retcode === CL_VIRUS)
{
    echo "Virus Detected! {$virus_name}";
}
```

Congratulations! You can find other functions [here](http://php-clamav.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: during "yum install clamav-devel", it gives this error : --> Finished Dependency Resolution
clamav-devel-0.97.7-1.el5.i386 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: clamav = 0.97.7-1.el5 is needed by package clamav-devel-0.97.7-1.el5.i386 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: clamav = 0.97.7-1.el5 is needed by package clamav-devel-0.97.7-1.el5.i386 (epel). What should I do?

Comment: nvm the missing dependency is solved by "yum remove clamav*"

Comment: @JordayDoyle Awesome it work!! Thank you. by any chance, do you know why the page is take a long time to load now? about 5 seconds, when my index.php consist only <?php echo cl_info(); ?>

Comment: It did the same on my localhost @Harts I believe it has something to do with ClamAV. What speed does it load if you scan an empty file?

Comment: around 7-10 seconds. in which if there were 2 upload forms, it will cause php max execution too long because it will become around 20 seconds or so

Comment: In my case doing cl_info() shows blank. What can be the root cause?