# In Sentora i will need to integrate a clamav Module

Tags: antivirus-integration, sentora

Could you please give an idea to integrate a clamav antivirus into sentora. I have already installed a clamav in centOS 6 . But i need a module integration for user error check. could you please give an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry , I have a solution for this question [How to install PHP clamav on CENTOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658450/how-to-install-php-clamav-on-centos) . kindly avoid this question